# Change selection style of a Worksheet in Excel to mimic RefEdit

Tags: .net, excel, dll, worksheet, vba

I need to build a control to select ranges in Excel using .Net. I have found some pretty good controls over the internet that mimic the VBA RefEdit. But all of them don't seem to have the same behaviour of the old RefEdit. They behaviour as Method (1), describe below:

When you are in Excel, inside a worksheet and select cells, the selection will have a light blue background and a thick black border around the selection.
Method (1):
[image: Selection Method (1) using common mouse dragging in Excel]

When using the Excel built-in control or the VBA RefEdit to select ranges in Excel, the mode of selection changes. It turns into a transparent background and it has a thin-dashed-animated border around the selection. Besides, it shows the number of rows and columns close to the mouse cursor while the left-mouse button is pressed (5R x 5C for 5 rows and 5 columns selection, for example). Method (2):

[image: Selection Method (2) using mouse dragging in a range control selection]

So, my question is, can I tell the worksheet (or something else) that I want to select ranges using method (2) instead of (1)? My first thought is to get this done using VBA. Then, after figuring out the property/method that handles this, I could propagate it to .Net and finish the .Net RefEdit 100% similar to the VBA.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't anything in the Excel OM exposed to VBA that controls this.

Comment: Have you considered using the Excel dialog directly via automation ? - then it would be an exact match...

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do this (how to use the Excel dialog via automation). Could you give me a more detailed explanation, please? Will I need to use the Excel instance process of my C# application?